# React Native HTMLToPDF printing awkward character

Tags: react-native, pdf-generation

So I have this HTML template to transform to pdf using the RNHTMLToPDF package:

```
    export default function getPdfTemplate(requestData, items, switchValues) {

  return `
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%;">

        <div id="pdf-header" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%;">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 50%;">
                <div style="font-size: 10px"> <b>Nome do cliente: </b> ${requestData.nomeCliente} </div>
                <div style="font-size: 10px"> <b>Código do cliente: </b> ${
                  requestData.codigoCliente
                } </div>
                <div style="font-size: 10px"> <b>Número do pedido: </b> ${requestData.numPedido} </div>
                <div style="font-size: 10px"> <b>Gerado em: </b> ${new Date().toLocaleDateString()} via Sistema de vendas </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 50%;">
                <div style="font-size: 10px"> <b>Data da negociação: </b> ${moment(
                  requestData.dataPedido,
                  "YYYYMMDD"
                ).format("DD/MM/YYYY")} - ${requestData.horaPedido} </div>
                <div style="font-size: 10px"> <b>Quantidade de itens: ${
                  requestData.quantidadeItem
                } </b>  </div>
                <div style="font-size: 10px"> <b>Valor total do pedido: </b> R$ ${
                  requestData.valorTotalPedido
                } </div>
                <div style="font-size: 10px"> <b>Valor do desconto negociado: </b> R$ ${
                  requestData.discount
                } </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr style="margin: 14px 0 8px 0;">
        <div id="pdf-table">
            <h2 style="font-size: 10px; margin: 8px 0;">Lista de itens do pedido</h2>
            <table style="background-color: #F3F3F4; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse" >
            <thead style="background-color: #656F7B;" >
                <tr style="color: #FFF; font-size: 8px;" >
                  <th style="padding: 5px; font-size: 8px;">MERCADORIA</th>
                  <th style="padding: 5px; font-size: 8px;">QTDE</th>
                  <th style="padding: 5px; font-size: 8px;">COD BARRAS</th>
                  <th style="padding: 5px; font-size: 8px;">UNIT.LI+IMP</th>
                  <th style="padding: 5px; font-size: 8px;">TOL.LIQ+IMP</th>
                  <th style="padding: 5px; font-size: 8px;">COND PGTO</th>
                  <th style="padding: 5px; font-size: 8px;">VLR.FRETE</th>
                  <th style="padding: 5px; font-size: 8px;">FIL EXPED</th>
                  <th style="padding: 5px; font-size: 8px;">FIL FAT</th>
                  <th style="padding: 5px; font-size: 8px;">% DE ICMS</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                    ${
                      items && items.length > 0 ? (
                        items.map(
                          (item, index) =>
                            `<tr style="line-height: 45px; background:${
                              index % 2 != 0 ? "#FFFFFF" : "initial"
                            }">
                                <td colspan="10" style="padding: 0px 10px; text-align:start; font-size: 8px;">${item.CODMER} - ${item.DESMER}</td>
                                <!--td colspan="9" style="font-size: 8px;"></td-->
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="margin: 4px 10px; line-height: 45px; background:${
                              index % 2 != 0 ? "#FFFFFF" : "initial"
                            }">
                                <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 6px;"> - </td>
                                <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 6px;">${
                                  item.quantidadeMercadoria
                                }</td> <!-- qtd -->  
                                <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 6px;">${
                                  item.CODBRRMER
                                }</td> <!-- cód barras item --> 
                                <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 6px;">
                                    ${(
                                      item.VLRLIQMER +
                                      item.VLRFRTMER +
                                      item.stb.valorSTBTotal +
                                      item.valorIPITotal
                                    ).toFixed(2)}
                                </td> <!-- Valor Unitário Líquido + Imposto + Frete --> 
                                <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 6px;">
                                    ${(
                                      (item.VLRLIQMER + item.VLRFRTMER) *
                                        item.quantidadeMercadoria +
                                      item.stb.valorSTBTotal +
                                      item.valorIPITotal
                                    ).toFixed(2)}
                                </td> <!-- Total líquido + Imposto + Frete --> 
                                <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 6px;">${
                                  item.condicaoPagamento.codigoCondicaoPagamento
                                }</td> <!-- condição de pagamento --> 
                                <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 6px;">${
                                  switchValues.freightValue ? item.frete : ''
                                }</td> <!-- valor frete --> 
                                <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 6px;">${
                                  switchValues.exp ? item.CODFILEPD : ''
                                }</td> <!-- filial expedição --> 
                                <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 6px;">${
                                  switchValues.fat ? item.CODFILFAT : ''
                                }</td> <!-- filial faturamento --> 
                                <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 6px;">
                                    ${
                                      switchValues.icms
                                        ? item.mercadoria.percentualICMS
                                            .percentualICMSMercadoria
                                        : ''
                                    }</td> <!-- percentual ICMS --> 
                            </tr>` 
                        )
                      ) : null
                    }
                
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div id="pdf-footer">
            <br>
            <hr>
            <h2 style="font-size: 10px;">Observações</h2>
            <div style="border: 1px solid #9BA3A8; border-radius: 8px; margin: 8px 0; padding: 12px; font-size: 6px;">
                ** ATENÇÃO! As informações deste arquivo destinam-se a mera conferência da descrição, quantidade e valor (nesta data) dos itens pedidos, sendo certo que, até o faturamento da mercadoria, o pedido poderá sofrer alterações, seja pela falta de produto em estoque, por variações de alíquotas de ICMS, IPI, débitos do cliente perante o Fisco Estadual, entre outros motivos, razão pela qual este documento não vincula as partes.
            </div>

            <div style="border: 1px solid #9BA3A8; border-radius: 8px; margin: 8px 0; padding: 12px; font-size: 6px;">
                ** Informamos ainda, que o presente pedido encontra-se em aberto até a data do faturamento, pelo que V. Sa. poderá promover o cancelamento ou a inclusão de novos itens, o que poderá provocar a modificação dos percentuais de desconto, influenciando no preço final dos pedidos.
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
    `
}
```

> Printing this awkward comma character. I can't find it anywhere in the respective HTML

[image]

Any reason for this mystery?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem

Just had to add a join at the end of the map function item.map(el...).join('')